# GNUPLOT: Capital gamma in times new roman

Tags: gnuplot, symbols

I want to write the xtics font in times new roman, but one letter is the Symbol Gamma. 
The code before the plot input is

```
reset
set encoding utf8
set xtics font "times new roman, 15"
set ylabel ("E[eV]")
set yrange[-2:2]

set xtics(" ~^J^{/Symbol=16 ^-}" 0.00000, " ~^{/Symbol G}^{/Symbol=16 ^-}" 0.66460, " ~^K^{/Symbol=16 ^-}" 1.60450, " ~^J^{/Symbol=16 ^-}" 2.26910)
```

The other stuff is just added because I needed a bar above each letter. 
So the question is: what should I use instead of

```
{/Symbol G}
```

in order to get the Gamma in times new roman like the other letters.

I don't want to use the latex enhancement because I tried it once and the output was just ugly. So please take into account that I just want to use a *.p file.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your terminal in in `enhanced` mode. You have already set the encoding properly. Make sure that your editor *actually encodes* your file as UTF-8!

*If* your `times new roman` actually contains the glyph for `Γ` (code-point 0x0393), then just insert this symbol into the gnuplot file.

Comment: Didn't know, that's possible. It actually worked by insertig the Γ right in the editor, which is for Linux: strg+shift+u and then enter 0393

(just for other users) Thank you!

Comment: @Mara01010011 You're welcome. :-) The key combination depends on the editor you use. In Emacs and Vim you can use [RFC 1345](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1345) mnemonics. For example in Vim I would type `ctrl-k` and then `G*` to get Γ.